# How to test my blocking queue actually blocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, unit-testing, c++11, blocking

I have a blocking queue (it would be really hard for me to change its implementation), and I want to test that it actually blocks. In particular, the `pop` methods must block if the queue is empty and unblock as soon as a `push` is performed. See the following pseudo C++11 code for the test:

```
BlockingQueue queue; // empty queue

thread pushThread([] 
{ 
    sleep(large_delay);
    queue.push(); 
});

queue.pop();
```

Obviously it is not perfect, because it may happen that the whole thread `pushThread` is executed and terminates before `pop` is called, even if the delay is large, and the larger the delay the more I have to wait for the test being over.

How can I properly ensure that `pop` is executed before `push` is called and that is blocks until `push` returns?

Comment: Generally you can't in standard c++, because to the other threads, a blocking thread looks the same as a thread that was put to sleep by the scheduler. Practically speaking, waiting 50ms or so should be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible without adding some extra state and interfaces to your BlockingQueue.

Proof goes something like this. You want to wait until the reading thread is blocked on `pop`. But there is no way to distinguish between that and the thread being about to execute the `pop`. This remains true no matter what you put just before or after the call to `pop` itself.

If you really want to fix this with 100% reliability, you need to add some state inside the queue, guarded by the queue's mutex, that means "someone is waiting". The `pop` call then has to update that state just before it atomically releases the mutex and goes to sleep on the internal condition variable. The `push` thread can obtain the mutex and wait until "someone is waiting". To avoid a busy loop here, you will want to use the condition variable again.

All of this machinery is nearly as complicated as the queue itself, so maybe you will want to test it, too... This sort of multi-threaded code is where concepts like "code coverage" -- and arguably even unit testing itself -- break down a bit. There are just too many possible interleavings of operations.

In practice, I would probably go with your original approach of sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
struct async_queue {
  T pop() {
    auto l = lock();
    ++wait_count;
    cv.wait( l, [&]{ return !data.empty(); } );
    --wait_count;
    auto r = std::move(data.front());
    data.pop_front();
    return r;
  }
  void push(T in) {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      data.push_back( std::move(in) );
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  void push_many(std::initializer_list<T> in) {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      for (auto&& x: in) 
        data.push_back( x );
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  std::size_t readers_waiting() {
    return wait_count;
  }
  std::size_t data_waiting() const {
    auto l = lock();
    return data.size();
  }
private:
  std::queue<T> data;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::atomic<std::size_t> wait_count{0};
  auto lock() const { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }

};
```

or somesuch.

In the push thread, busy wait on `readers_waiting` until it passes 1.

At which point you have the lock and are within `cv.wait` before the lock is unlocked.  Do a `push`.

In theory an infinitely slow reader thread could have gotten into `cv.wait` and still be evaluating the first lambda by the time you call `push`, but an infinitely slow reader thread is no different than a blocked one...

This does, however, deal with slow thread startup and the like.

Using `readers_waiting` and `data_waiting` for anything other than debugging is usually code smell.

Comment: OT: I prefer using brace initialization for `unique_lock` or `lock_guard` from personal (bad) experience regarding the "most-vexing parse", although that's not relevant in the given code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::condition_variable` to accomplish this. The help page of cppreference.com actually shows a very nice cosumer-producer example which should be exactly what you are looking for: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

EDIT: Actually the german version of cppreference.com has an even better example :-) http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Where would you wait and where would you signal?

Comment: Start two threads, one for `pop()` and one for `push`. Wait after `pop()` and signal after `push()`. Make sure you start the `push()` thread after the `pop()` thread.

Comment: @SamerTufail I think you just added complexity without really solving the problem. How do you ensure push is called after pop in your solution?

Comment: @Nick, You start your push thread after pop and probably signal after your pop to your push thread, so two condition variables.

Comment: Probably? How do you start the thread after pop if the main thread is blocked there? Waiting for the queue not to be empty?

Comment: Main thread is not blocked both push and pop are on seperate threads...

Comment: It does not matter how you call it. The thread where you call pop is blocked and you can't start push thread after that... why don't you write your solution? It would be way clearer to discuss about it.

Comment: @SamerTufail: what Nick is trying to say is that no matter in which order you start threads you don't know in which order even the first instruction of their thread functions will be executed